# is it possible to send push notification to only active clients using firebase cloud messaging and node.js server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know wether it is possible to send push notification using firebase cloud messaging and node.js server? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible using either `API endpoints` provided by `firebase` or by using `firebase-admin` npm package.

Minimal Example -

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin')

if (!firebaseAdmin.apps.length) {
  firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccountJson),
    databaseURL: databaseUrl
  })
}

// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
const registrationToken = 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN';

const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
firebaseAdmin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

For further documentation please refer to -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message